# Converting string to binary and back to string is not the same with PHP

Tags: php

I came up with the PHP code below which converts a binary string `00000010` to the string "representation" and then later I convert it back to the binary string, however it's not getting back the same original binary string `00000010`. The code below works perfectly with `10000010`, `11000010`... but for some strange reason it does not work with `00000010`. Why?

```
$binary = '00000010';
echo $binary . "\n";

$temp = pack('H*',dechex(bindec($binary)));
echo str_pad(decbin(ord($temp)),8,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

OUTPUT:

```
00000010
00100000
```

I know some string "representation" of some binary strings are not visible/printable chars, but I dont care printing those chars. I just want to convert it to that string "representation" and back, but it's not working. What I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

After great help of @Rocket Hazmat the code started working for some binaries but not for others. The code below, for example, does not look to work, it outputs `0` instead of `10101010`.

```
$binary = '10101010';
$temp = pack('C',base_convert($binary,2,16));
echo base_convert(ord($temp),16,2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pack()` with `h*` (or `h`) is what you want here.  You are reading it in as a hex value (after converting from binary), so you want `pack` to see it as a hex value.

```
$temp = pack('h', base_convert($binary, 2, 16));
```

The problem was when you convert it back.  `ord` returns you a base 10 number.  I was incorrectly converting it as a hex (base 16) value:

```
base_convert(ord($temp), 10, 2)
```

Though, after looking at the code again, I think you don't even need `pack()` here.  You are using `ord()`, so we can use its opposite, `chr()`:

```
$temp = chr(base_convert($binary, 2, 10));
```

`chr()` wants a (base 10) int though, not a hex value, so let's use that.

What seems to be working is the following:

```
$temp = chr(base_convert($binary, 2, 10));
echo str_pad(base_convert(ord($temp), 10, 2), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: I had realized that using `h*` would solve my problem BUT using `h*` will fail to convert  for example `10000010` go and back - and in this case if I use `H*` it will work.

Comment: @Samul I see... yes, it is failing for `10000010` and `h*`...

Comment: So how do I create a code that knows when to use H and h? Because you are right, using `h*` solves the problem to convert `00000010` go and back, but it breaks all the other binary string that I tried with `H*`! BTW, thanks for pointing about the `*` :)

Comment: @Samul: I see the issue.  Instead of `h` or `H`, you actually want `C`.  And you can simplify the `dechex`/`bindec`/`dechex` using `base_convert`.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Samul Check the updated answer I posted, I think I got it all working.

Comment: Worked perfectly my friend, you nailed it! Thanks for not only posting the code, your comments were very valuable!

Comment: My friend, I tried your most recent code with the string `10101010` and it does not work, it returns `0`. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Samul Or maybe I didn't test it all the way, or maybe `pack()` still confuses me a bit :-P

Comment: kkkkk I edited the question to reflect your answer. Anyway, I appreciate your attention and if you find a solution please let me now :)

Comment: @Samul I am working on it.  I think I see what I did wrong.

Comment: @Samul Have another look.  I think I was just handling the numbers wrong.

Comment: I am amazed how people usually come up with solutions that are even simpler and more elegant than the ones I thought was already "optimized". Anyway, I already tried your code, and worked perfetly, without pack! Thanks a lot!!!